# Drop down box, Object required

Tags: vba, combobox, powerpoint

I have constructed following code. Here we click on a combobox in a power point display and the date is the selected from a list. For some reason I am getting a

> Object required run time 424 error

Do I need to set the object?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
   Call AddDropDownItemsFromDate(1)
End If
End Sub

 Sub AddDropDownItemsFromDate(i As Integer)
 Dim nIndex As Integer
 Dim Selector As Integer
 Selector = i

 Select Case Selector
  Case Is = 1
  For nIndex = 0 To 3600
   ComboBox1.AddItem DateAdd("d", nIndex, CVDate("10/02/2007"))
  Next nIndex
  Case Is = 2 
   ....other combobox's
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: sorry guys, the line ComboBox1.AddItem DateAdd("d", nIndex, CVDate("10/02/2007"))

Comment: The sub  AddDropDownItemsFromDate is in a separate module. Perhaps this is the issue

Comment: You will need to call the sub with the module prefix, like Module1.AddDropDownItemsFromDate

Comment: yep...we needed the SlideX (x being whatever number) number in front of CombobBox